# How to read saved image and locate it in coordinates without any distortins?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, imread

I can't overcome maybe very simple obstacle. First, I am doing some spatial operations with shape files, plot the results and save the image:

```
# read different shape-files, overlaying them, sjoining them`
...
# plotting results:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10, 10])

ax.set_xlim(left=9686238.14, right=9727068.02)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=7070076.66, top=7152463.12)

# various potting like objects.plot(ax=ax, column = 'NAME', cmap='Pastel2', k=6, legend=False) and many others

plt.axis('equal')           
plt.savefig('back11.png', dpi=300)
plt.close()
```

Thus I got such a nice picture back11.png:
[image]

Second, I am reading that picture and (in the same cordinates) want to see absolutlely identical one map11.png:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10, 10])
ax.set_xlim(left=9686238.14, right=9727068.02)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=7070076.66, top=7152463.12)

back = plt.imread('back11.png')
ax.imshow(back, extent=[9686238.14, 9727068.02, 7070076.66, 7152463.12])
plt.axis('equal')
plt.savefig('map11.png', dpi=300)
plt.close()
```

But really I got something else (map11.png):
[image]

What is the origin of such a strange mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

When `matplotlib` is showing an image using `plt.imshow`, it automatically adds axis and white space around it (regardless of the image content). While your image is accidentally another plot, which contains axis and white space itself. To solve that problem, use

```
plt.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1)
plt.axis('off')
```

which should output nothing but the image.

But on the other hand, you have to specify `plt.figure(figsize=xxx, dpi=xxx)` correctly in order to get THE stored image (correct size, no interpolation or re-sampling). If you simply want to see the image using python (and you are in `jupyter` notebook), you can use `Pillow`. If you convert the image to a `PIL.Image` object, it is by itself displayable by `jupyter` REPL.

If you are not inside `jupyter`, you might also directly open the image using os image viewer. It is at least more convenient than matplotlib to display the "exact" image.

BTW, when displaying the image, the same parameters do not apply any more (since its an image and all parameters are hidden inside the content of it). Therefore, there's no need (and it's wrong) to write all those magic numbers. Also if you want to save the image without white border and axis, use the code above before calling `plt.savefig`

Comment: Thanks a lot, subplot_adjust(...) was new to me! Unfortunatly your proposal to use `plt.figure(figsize=[10,10], dpi=300)` leads to an absolutly empty picture in coordinates -0.04-0.04 at X and Y, nevetheless I later use `ax.imshow(back, extent=[9686238.14, 9727068.02, 7070076.66, 7152463.12])`, where extent - is a location, where I want to place many other information. If I'll comment plt.figure(...), picture will become as previous... I know about plt.axis('off') and didn't use it becouse wanted to do problem more visual.